# XPath to link based on anchor text?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I was wondering can someone help me on how to generate a robust XPath for the following button.

```
<a href="/webApplcation#/submittedApps" accesskey="n">Submitted Applications</a>
```

The button I am trying to click is the submitted applications button.

I tried this XPath but it is not being identified

```
 //div[contains(normalize-space(),'Submitted Applications')]
```

I can use the complete XPath but it is not very robust if something changes on the layout of the web application.

```
 //*[@id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"]/ul/li[1]/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
//div[contains(normalize-space(),'Submitted Applications')]
```

to

```
//a[contains(normalize-space(),'Submitted Applications')]
```

or better yet,

```
//a[normalize-space()='Submitted Applications']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! Apologies I should have noticed the tag being a rather than div. Thank you :)